# automatic browsing + ip spoofing using pcap.net

Tags: ip, web-crawler, spoofing, pcap.net

Using PCAP.NET, I want to automatic browse with the feature of changing ip address. I want to browse a website and send data to it (filling a form using POST) with different ip addresses each time.

[Automatic Browsing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5452/Microsoft-Web-Browser-Automation-using-C)

Someone suggested that I must use PCAP.NET for ip spoofing but I don't know who to use PCAP.NET inside automatic browsing tool.

Can somebody tell me where to begin or tell me who to send post data using PCAP.NET?

Thanks!

Comment: unless you're doing this locally, you can **NOT** spoof ip addresses for TCP connections. at most you can send the initial SYN packet, and then the process breaks. And we are not here to tell you how to use a library. **YOU** write some code and we'll maybe help fix it.

Comment: Actually @MarcB B, it's quite possible to spoof IP addresses for TCP connections. The problem begins when you want to receive the response. If you manage to choose the spoofed address carefully so that you can somehow see the response, it could work. You basically need to choose a spoofed IP address that packets to it will be routed to some network you have access to, not trivial, but still sometimes possible. Regarding using Pcap.Net, I suggest you start by following the tutorial and examples available at Pcap.Net: [link](http://pcapdot.net).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, what do you mean by choose ip that packets will be route to some network you have access to???!! Should I have a dedicated ip address?? or by using DHCP assigned ip address is possible?